# How to find CiviCRM version in SQL from a database backup

Tags: sql, backups

I have a backup of a CiviCRM database from some time ago that I'd like to inspect inside a test site. When setting up the test site, I want to use the correct release version to match the version at the time the backup was made. How can I execute an SQL query on this orphan database to determine which version of the CiviCRM codebase its schema is compatible with?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could use phpmyadmin and look in table 'civicrm_domain' at field 'version' - the version is stored there.